# Calculating Visits per Location by Customer

Tags: excel, count

Good afternoon, everyone! I'm working in Excel to compute counts of customer visits to various locations and am running in circles trying to figure this out. In short, I have a table such as:

```
CustomerID: Location:   Date: 
1           Tacotown    6/9
1           Happytown   6/10
1           Happytown   6/11
2           Tacotown    6/11
```

And would like to create a totals column specific to each customer and location so that the table would be:

```
CustomerID: Location:   Date:   TotalCustomerVisitsAtLocation:
1           Tacotown    6/9      1
1           Happytown   6/10     2
1           Happytown   6/11     2
2           Tacotown    6/11     1
```

I know I could find this information in a pivot table or could create columns for each location to calculate totals, but for reasons a totals column would be ideal.

Any tips or ideas are greatly appreciated! Thank you for your time and have a pleasant afternoon.

Comment: You can use `COUNTIFS` for this, where your criteria are CustomerID and Location.

Comment: Thanks for the information. I tried out that formula but couldn't get it to work properly. With the given example table what would the formula be?

Comment: `=COUNTIFS(A:A,A1,B:B,B1)`. Or maybe `A2` and `B2` if your data begins in row 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `COUNTIFS` for this, where your criteria are CustomerID and Location.

If your data begins in row 2, for example:

```
=COUNTIFS(A:A,A2,B:B,B2)
```